# Can I access what was once `tf.get_global_step()` from within a custom Keras layer?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm implementing a custom Layer with the Keras API (working with `TF2.0-beta`). I want to use the epoch number in my calculation in order to decay a parameter over time (meaning - in the `call()` method).

I'm used to `tf.get_global_step()` but understand that TF deprecated all global scopes, and definitely for a good reason.

If I had the model instance, I could use `model.optimizer.iterations`, but I'm not sure how I get the instance of my parent model when I'm implementing a Layer.

Do I have any way to do that or the only way is to let the layer expose a Callback that will update the parameter I want to decay? Other ideas? Ideally something that wouldn't make the user of the layer aware of that inner detail (that's why I don't like the Callback approach - user has to add them to the model).

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If yes, how? I asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61329343/3924118.

Comment: As far as I understand this - if you write a general Layer (which can be used by others), you shouldn't rely on the "step" as every optimizer has a different notion of it and your layer could end up being used by many of them. 
If you're the only one using your layer, I guess you could add a variable and increment it with a Keras callback or a similar trick.